# Two row header to one row header for a data frame in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, header, multi-index

I have a data set with a multi-index, 2-dimensional header. I would like to merge it into one header row by removing empty column names in the first row by previous non nan column name in the same row.

Below showing structure of dataframe I have.
First two rows are header.

```
         id  One             Two      
  response   X1   Y1   Z1    X2    Y2
0        0  1.1  1.2  1.4  1.11  1.22
1        1  1.1  1.2  1.3  1.11  1.22
2        2  1.1  1.2  1.1  1.11  1.22
```

I want to change above data frame to one in below,

```
   id  One 1.X1  One 2.Y1  One 3.Z1  Two 1.X2  Two 2.Y2
0   0       1.1       1.2       1.4      1.11      1.22
1   1       1.1       1.2       1.3      1.11      1.22
2   2       1.1       1.2       1.1      1.11      1.22
```

Actual data frame has more than 100 columns.

Hope someone can help me here.

Than you so much.

Mary Abin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your columns are indeed a `MultiIndex`

i.e

```
print(df.columns)

MultiIndex([( 'id', 'response'),
            ('One',       'X1'),
            ('One',       'Y1'),
            ('One',       'Z1'),
            ('Two',       'X2'),
            ('Two',       'Y2')],
           )
```

then we can pass them into a new data frame and use a cumulative count on the first level before flattening the columns.

```
s = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.columns)
s['col'] =  (s.groupby(0).cumcount()+1).astype(str) + '.'
#skip the first row and re-order columns to match your desired order.
df.columns = ['id'] + s.iloc[1:, [0,2,1]].astype(str).agg(' '.join,1).tolist()
```

---

```
print(df)

   id  One 1. X1  One 2. Y1  One 3. Z1  Two 1. X2  Two 2. Y2
0   0        1.1        1.2        1.4       1.11       1.22
1   1        1.1        1.2        1.3       1.11       1.22
2   2        1.1        1.2        1.1       1.11       1.22


print(s)
    0         1 col
0   id  response  1.
1  One        X1  1.
2  One        Y1  2.
3  One        Z1  3.
4  Two        X2  1.
5  Two        Y2  2.
```

Comment: I tried this code, but it couldn't provide the desired result. Anyway, thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: @JKdMwA whats wrong with the output ? it mathces your input

Comment: Here is the screenshot from Jupyter. https://imgur.com/GbzjIE8  But it worked on the terminal.

Comment: When I tried it in new jupyter page, it gave desired result.

Answer (score -1):

df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)

Check this https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html

Comment: This one also doesn't work. The code just selects one row as a header without merging header rows. Thank you for your response here.